# Apache 2 WebDAV, server trash folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav, mod-webdav

I've just started experimenting with WebDAV under Apache 2.2 on CentOS 5. It works well although the Windows WebDAV client is clunky and nowhere near as seamless as it should be.

When a user deletes a file through WebDAV, is there a way to have it moved to a specified folder on the server rather than deleted?
So you could setup a sort of trash folder so that anything deleted could be recoverable by an admin with server access?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native functionality like this. I'd recommend just using some sort of incremental backup script like [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) or [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/). Either of these will maintain a GFS, incremental backup rotation for you, and can keep backup copies locally or on a remote host.